# Fantasy manga where op mc can use all types of magic and tries to learn them from a small, genius elf magician

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I don't quite remember if it's a reincarnation story, but it is a story based in a fantasy world.

The scene I remember from the manga is where the mc tries to buy scrolls to learn magic, but the shop he is introduced to only sells scrolls to those she deem worthy.
The shopkeeper is a tiny elf magician who is known as a genius, capable of using more elements than most people (or everyone, maybe it was 6 elements), and she decides to test out mc's magic ability.

He is tested to be able to use all (8?) types of magic, and when he tries out a weak fire magic (flare I think it was called?) to light a candle as the elf told him to do so, instead of lighting the candle as normal, he brings forth an enormous pillar of fire onto the candle.

As well, everytime mc surprises the elf genius with his aptitude of all elements and his magical output, the elf shakes (it looks like she's vibrating violently) in shock.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this? Do you recall the names of any characters or places?  What were all the elements?

Comment: I think I read it a couple of years ago. The names of the characters I can't recall, only this one scene. I think the elements were the fire, water, earth, wind, dark, light, non-element (like enhancement magic), and I forgot the last. I'm sorry for the lack of info, but I suddenly recalled this manga and wanted to read it again.

Comment: Do you remember any details about the protagonist, besides being over powered and multi-elemental?

Comment: Sadly, no. Overpowered I'm sure he is, and the only thing I can think of is that he was surprised about his magical output along with the elf. I think him trying out the flare magic was his first time using magic. He asked the elf if the pillar of fire was suppose to happen, and the elf replied that it wasn't.

Comment: "Shoukan sareta Kenja wa Isekai wo Yuku" has a tiny genius elf mage, but does not appear to have that specific scene, at least within the first 8 chapters. He's using magic and there's no mention of elemental affinity, so I doubt it's this.